# Where to find (people) master data (citizenship/countries/education/...)

Tags: .net, datasource

folks!

Im searching for a reliable source of master data. we have to deal with personal data and need therefore lists of possible citizenships, countries, education etc.

Is there a reliable source for data like that? Some cross-country standardized data source?

Many thanks and BR

Comment: maybe WikiData https://www.wikidata.org ?

Comment: This one provide details about countries and of course list of countries. https://restcountries.eu/